# spring boot with hibernate envers migration script mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, migration, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with creating the MySQL database with migration scripts in spring boot. I'm using flyway and there is no problem with the configuration.

As you see in the picture below, that is the code I'm using to create users table, and I'm doing so with all the other tables. I'm also using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in application properties of the spring boot application.

I'm getting two errors that I don't understand, these are:

1. Table 'database.users' doesn't exist
2. Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table users add column banned bit, not null]

Does someone understand why I'm getting this error? Appreciate your help!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banned` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

stack trace:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at com.flype.system.FlypebackendApplication.main(FlypebackendApplication.java:27) [main/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table users add column banned bit not null]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.migrateTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'flype_dev.users' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1603) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2631) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1529) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.executeUpdate(StatementHandle.java:497) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

part of build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '2.9.0'
    compile group: 'com.jolbox', name: 'bonecp', version: '0.8.0.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.3.RELEASE")
    compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache')
    compile(group: 'net.sf.ehcache', name: 'ehcache')
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.8.47'
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.0.12.Final'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.11.0'


    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integrationTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
}
```

Comment: Perhaps including the stack trace of the error might help.  Also, thus far I don't see what this has to do with `hibernate-envers`.

Comment: @Naros Im also creating all the other audit tables with such scripts, but there is no problem in audit tables according to the stack trace. I added the stacktrace in the post.

Comment: Are you sure that both Hibernate and Flyway are pointing to the same database or schema?

Comment: @Naros Thanks for fixing the stack trace. Yes I'm pretty sure, because when I change to create, it does work without any problem, and If I delete the migrations and just use create-drop and build with hibernate, it does also work.

Comment: @Naros the code for the table above, notice that I got it from Mysql work bench through exporting data after building the database with hibernate.

Comment: @Naros sorry for writing a bit too much, I want to mention that I tried to use validate instead of update with flyway, but it does complain about the audit tables created by hibernate envers, how do I use validate with the audit table any idea?

Comment: Can you post pom.xml or gradle.build ? 
I think spring-data-jpa is not compatible with the hibernate version

Comment: @PRATHAPS I added gradle.build file in the post. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe you need to pick one or the other to manage your schema.  Having flyway modify the schema and then having Hibernate use `update` seems like it could lead to issues.  I would think that `validate` on the Hibernate side makes more logical sense to check that what your flyway scripts have done was accurate.

Comment: @Naros ok that is a good tip, but when I use validate, it does complain that audit tables does not exists, what should I do with audit table, they should not be included in the script ?

Comment: If you are letting Flyway manage your schema migration, then all schema modifications, tables, etc should be included.  All Hibernate will then do is validate that the schema it determines should exist is correct based on the supplied entity mappings and the additional entity mappings for Envers.

Comment: @Naros good point, but I think that because there is no entity class that represents the audit tables, it will not be known for the project and it will result in complains about not finding these tables. Which is exactly what I'm getting when I use validate, how do I solve this problem any suggestions? Appreciate your help!

Comment: In development, you can always allow Hibernate to manage your schema using `update` but then when you migrate to your QA and PRD environments, you could use Flyway (with Hibernate using `validate`) and easily be able to generate the database diffs needed for migrating those environments for the Envers tables like you might do with Hibernate too.

Comment: @Naros thanks for all advices, I solved the issue. It was wrong path, the default path is db/migration and I had it under db only.